# Find all string positions in file

Tags: python

If i want to find position of string in a file i can do

```
f = open('file.txt', 'r')
lines = f.read()
posn = lines.find('string')
```

What if the string occured several times in the file and I want to find all the positions where it occurs? I have a list of strings so right now my code is

```
for string in list:
    f = open('file.txt', 'r')
    lines = f.read()
    posn = lines.find(string)
```

My code is incomplete, it only finds the first position of each string in the list

Comment: My code is incomplete, it only finds the first position of each string in the list

Comment: Edited the question! Post it along the ques the next time you post. All the best :) GD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following

```
import re

a = open("file", "r")
g = a.read()
ma = re.finditer('test', g)
for t in ma:
    print t.start(), t.end()
```

Possible output

> 8 12
>
> 16 20

---

#### For example:

```
g='hahahatesthahatesthahahatest'
ma=re.finditer('test',g)
for t in ma:
    print t.start(), t.end()
```

Output

> 6 10
>
> 14 18
>
> 24 28

---

`print g[t.start():t.end()]` gives you `test` as expected

Comment: Also i get this  when i print the result of re.search()->  <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0000000001E25168>

Comment: @Illusionist, that's correct, you've found what u wanted. Use methods of re.MatchObject to deal with it.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! very educational !

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `enumerate` :

```
>>> s='this is a string'
>>> def find_pos(s,sub):
...     return [i for i,j in enumerate(s) if j==sub]
... 

>>> find_pos(s,'s')
[3, 6, 10]
```

Answer (score 1):

This will return where your pattern is present in your file. Uses [re.finditer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer).

```
import re
with open('your.file') as f:
    text = f.read()
    positions = [m.span() for m in re.finditer('pattern', text)]
```